# Dynamicaly deleting widgets in Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have some widgets in Tkinter frame that I want to remove on Users click. There are some labels and for each label, there is a corresponding button to remove it. Here is the code for making the frame.

```
def delFav():
    win2 = Tk()
    widgets = []
    for url in urls:
        label = Label(win2, text = url)
        button = Button(win2, text = "Delete")
        widgets.append({"url" : url, "label" : label, "button" : button})
    for w in widgets:
        print w["url"], w["label"], w["button"]
        w["button"].configure(command = lambda : delete(w["url"], widgets))
        w["label"].pack()
        w["button"].pack()
```

The delete function looks like this:

```
def delete(url, widgets):
    for w in widgets:
        if w["url"] == url:
            print w["label"]
            print w["button"]
            w["label"].pack_forget()
            w["button"].pack_forget()
            return
```

When I want to delete a URL I press the associated button, but always the last button is removed. For eg, this is the output generated by clicking the 2nd delete button, out of the 3 buttons.

```
entry/13394 .44877224 .44877384
entry/13277 .44877464 .44877544
entry/8166 .44877624 .44877704
.44877624
.44877704
```

The first 3 lines show the widgets list, and on clicking the middle button, I get the last button and label names printed from the delete function as the last 2 lines.

Any button I click, only the last label and button disappear. How to correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old "late binding on functions declared in a loop" problem.

```
w["button"].configure(command = lambda : delete(w["url"], widgets))
```

On this line, the command `delete(w["url"], widgets)` assumes that `w` has the final value that `w` had when the loop finished, rather than the value it had when you called `configure`. So clicking any button always deletes the last label.

You can compel the lambda to "bind earlier" by passing w as a default argument.

```
w["button"].configure(command = lambda w=w: delete(w["url"], widgets))
```